# Minimize Objective Function

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima, simplex-method

**Formulation**

> Min $z$
> subject to constraints
>
> - $z \ge x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4-4$
> - $z \ge x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8-60$
> - $z \ge x_9+x_{10}+x_{11}+x_{12}$
> - $x_1+x_5+x_9 \ge 450$
> - $x_2+x_6+x_{10} \ge 200$
> - $x_3+x_7+x_{11} \ge 300$
> - $x_4+x_8+x_{12} \ge 300$
> - $131x_1+218x_{2}+266x_{3}+120x_{4}+250x_{5}+115x_{6}+263x_{7}+278x_{8}+178x_{9}+132x_{10}+122x_{11}+180x_{12} \ge 17000000$
> - $x_i\ge0$ for $i=1,2,\dots,12$

Can anyone tell me how to calculate this objective function in the simplex method? If there is no $x$ in the objective function, then how do I build up the tabular form?

Answer (score 0):

The $z$ is just another variable.  If it helps, rewrite $z$ as $x_{13}$, and then the objective coefficient vector is $(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)$.